# Stick together 2 floating divs almost work with jQuery - need help on polishing

Tags: jquery, html, floating

I've been working on this for the last few days and cannot get it to work perfect smooth.

The concept: on a multi-div page, the **navigation** should stick to the top of the window when scrolling down and when scrolling over the search, stick the search below the navigation.

---

Issues need to be fixed (just 2 main issues):

- After scrolling back to top of the window/document, the navigation does not lose the *floating* class.
- After the search gets stick below navigation div, continuing scrolling makes the **search** appear and disappear randomly (maybe), it should be always visible (is this a *parseFloat* matter?)
- OPTIONAL - like anyone out there, I would like an animation that could be added to search
  when sticking to the navigation
- OPTIONAL - make the search keep it's offset.left after changing the position from absolute to fixed even if the window/document gets resized

Here is a clone of my entire code:

http://jsfiddle.net/W2FR4/16/

Appreciate any suggestion.

Danny

Answer (score 0):

it addresses some of your problems I think. Have a look [there](http://jsfiddle.net/kwicher/jSVBJ/7).
K

Comment: Thanks K, this only fixes the navigation unstick on scroll top. The search div stick appear and disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Almost working like a charm.

http://jsfiddle.net/W2FR4/37/

Optionals need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kwicher. I already figured out that. Thanks a lot :)

http://jsfiddle.net/W2FR4/37/

In my setup here I can also make it keep the right positioning.
I just cannot get it to have some cool animation, but I can leave that for later.

Regards and thanks again,
Danny